# ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, nestjs

I am a beginner in node, nest, and docker but somehow I got assigned a job to dockerized all the existing node js applications.

I followed one of the [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BrlQthcUHGw) and successfully deployed the basic hello world via docker but in the next [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jYFyLLqvHy8&t=70s) when I am trying to add Postgres to the docker I am facing some issues in connecting to Postgres.

I am using docker desktop on mac.

**Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file code snippet**

```
version: "3.9"  # optional since v1.27.0
services:
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://user:password@postgres:5432/db
      NODE_ENV: developement
      PORT: 3000
    ports:
      - "8080:3000"
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.0
    ports:
      - "35000:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: db
```

**Here is the entire error log**

[image]

[Github Repository](https://github.com/prafful-panwar/docker-node-nest.git) of this project

Thank you for helping in advance :)

Comment: I think the problem was in code, API code connects to 127.0.0.1 and doesn't use env `DATABASE_URL`. Please check to connect code structure and make sure use `DATABASE_URL`

Comment: Try changing the database hostname so that your `api` connects on `postgres:5432`. Using `127.0.0.1` is for when you want to connect from outside your Docker network, and you'd then need to use port `127.0.0.1:35000`.

Comment: can you please attach Dockerfile  and al related project file

Comment: added project to github https://github.com/prafful-panwar/docker-node-nest.git @NaorTedgi

Comment: @Pooya I added the GitHub repo link also. database URL is there in app.module.ts file url: process.env.DATABSE_URL,

Comment: This problem was resolved by fixing [a typo](https://github.com/prafful-panwar/docker-node-nest/blame/0b952fde8910465ac9f401a49b544e5466141536/src/app.module.ts#L13)  So the question should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem for a typo in `DATABASE_URL`. In [code](https://github.com/prafful-panwar/docker-node-nest/blob/master/src/app.module.ts#L13) for connect database use `DATABSE_URL` word but in docker-compose used `DATABASE_URL`.

You should change `url: process.env.DATABSE_URL` to `url: process.env.DATABASE_URL`

Comment: updated but still same error :(

Comment: Are do use `docker-compose up --build`?

Comment: docker-compose up

Comment: You have to use with `--build` argument, because you changed code and need to build first and then run again

Comment: docker-compose up --build worked. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your connection string is correct in your `docker-compose.yml`. Just pass the host, port, user and pass seperated and let `TypeOrm` handle the connection.

```
// app.module.ts
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
    type: 'postgres',
    host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
    port: process.env.POSTGRES_PORT,
    username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
    password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
 })
```

And your docker-compose.yml:

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.9'
services:
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=promo-pass
      - POSTGRES_USER=promo-user
      - POSTGRES_DB=promo-api-db
      - POSTGRES_PORT=5432

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: promo-user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: promo-pass
      POSTGRES_DB: promo-api-db
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, After some investigation I found out the problem is with `host`. You should use `container_name` as a `host` value

docker-compose.yml is:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:16.1-alpine
    container_name: my-app-db
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "${POSTGRES_PORT}:${POSTGRES_PORT}"
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  db:
```

config db is:

```
const dbConfig = {
  port: Number(process.env.POSTGRES_PORT),
  user: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
  password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB
};

export const ormConfig: PostgresConnectionOptions = {
  type: "postgres",
  host: "my-app-db",
  port: dbConfig.port,
  database: dbConfig.database,
  username: dbConfig.user,
  password: dbConfig.password
};

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(ormConfig),
    ...
  ],
  providers: [AppService]
})
```

Answer (score -1):

In the normal case, without Docker, i. e. you are using node and postgresql on you development or production machine, you just want to start postgres service and enable it if you want.

In order to start your postgres service, type the following command:

> sudo systemctl start postgresql

To enable :

> sudo systemctl enable postgresql

**Note**:

1. "Enable" means enbable the postgres server at boot time.
2. In my environment, i am using Red Hat. So if commands doesn't work, find the corresponding command on your linux distribution or on your specific OS.

I hope this can help someone else!